# Row checkbox disappeared phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I upgrade wamp to the newest version and then to Phpmyadmin 4.0.4.
But something annoying happened some of my tables don't have checkbox on rows (see pictures below)

No checkbox:
[image: Bug checkbox ?]

Checkbox:
[image: Normal checkbox]

Is it a bug or can I have it back?

Comment: Is there something special about those rows compared to the ones that have the checkboxes? Does this happen with multiple browsers? Can you reproduce the problem on the demo server at http://demo.phpmyadmin.net ?

Comment: Do you see a warning message saying "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available." for the these tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that a table must have a primary key for phpMyAdmin to show you that checkbox.

Do your tables that are missing the checkbox, NOT have a primary key?

phpMyAdmin must have a unique way of addressing a row in order to perform row specific operations, obviously!

Comment: Yes the problem was the primary key. Thanks